# Selenium Code works on local machine but breaks when used in celery on heroku

Tags: django, selenium-webdriver, heroku, celery

I am developing a site in django where I have a task that uses selenium that takes place using celery, this task runs perfectly fine on my machine, but once hosted to heroku, It still runs but acts differently.

I have a selenium task where it logs in onto an account and posts a tweet using selenium, I use celery to schedule tasks like this.
When I try to run this locally, it works fine.

After hosting the website to heroku, Selenium doesnt want to log in for some reason.

That is my selenium code

```py
def test_login(self):
    driver = self.driver

    driver.get("https://twitter.com/i/flow/login")

    flag = True
    while flag:
        try:
            WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='text']"))).send_keys(self.username)
            time.sleep(1)
            driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Next')]").click()
            print("Username")

            password = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located(
                    (By.XPATH, "//input[@name='password']"))
            )
            if password:
                flag = False
        except:
            driver.refresh()

    password = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.XPATH, "//input[@name='password']"))
    )
    password.send_keys(self.password)
    print("Password")
    time.sleep(1)

    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Log in')]").click()

    try:
        email = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located(
                (By.XPATH, "//input[@autocomplete='email']"))
        )
        email.send_keys(self.email)
        time.sleep(1)

        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Next')]").click()
    except:
        pass

    time.sleep(5)  # Change to be url like login
    if driver.current_url == "https://twitter.com/i/flow/login":
        driver.close()
        driver.quit()
        return False

    if driver.current_url == "https://twitter.com/home":
        driver.close()
        driver.quit()
        return True
```

Anyone have any idea why its not working on heroku?

Comment: what does that mean acts differently, you should some details for others to understand

Comment: Formatted it, thank you for the notice